# What type of chart would you choose for this problem, and what charting library can provide it?

Tags: language-agnostic, open-source, visualization, charts

Suppose I have N segments, each one having a start and a end value, for example:

```
[1,40],[40,80],[80,100],[90,110]
```

I'd like to create a chart where I can display all of them, in such a way that I can see that the fourth segment overlaps the values of the third one.

I'm new to charting, can you suggest which chart type I could use for this kind of "problem"? Also, if you'd be able to suggest a library which supports that type of chart, that would be great. I can use any of : Java,Ruby,Python,Perl,.NET. The app that will generate this kind of chart will be ran on a Windows computer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement something like [Xinxua's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298162/what-type-of-chart-would-you-choose-for-this-problem-and-what-charting-library-c/2298314#2298314) in python using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import zeros

data = [[1,40],[40,80],[80,100],[90,110]]
N = len(data)
plt.figure()
start_points = [x[0] for x in data]
lengths = [x[1]-x[0] for x in data]
z = zeros(N)
plt.errorbar(x=start_points, y=range(N), xerr=[z,lengths], fmt='o', xuplims=True)
plt.grid(True)
plt.axis(ymax=N-.5)
```

Which would give you
[image: image of results using matplotlib]

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, I would suggest you to just use a simple Bar Chart, using the great [Google Bar Charts API](http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/apis/chart/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html). For example, for the data provided in in your question I would do a url like this

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=320x280
&chco=4D89F9,C6D9FD&chbh=r,0.5,3.0
&chds=0,130&chxt=x,y&chxr=1,0,130,0&chxl=0:|a|b|c|d|
&chd=t:1,40,80,90|40,80,100,110
```

...and google would return me a Chart like this.

[image: Google Chart API for your data]

As you can see, it's a simple GET request. And now they're supporting [POST requests](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/docs/post_requests.html) too.

In fact, I recommend you to do a simple search in [Google's Chart Gallery](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/docs/gallery/chart_gall.html). Even if you're not going to use it, at least you're going to have some really good examples for your project.

(The obvious disadvantage of this approach is the need of an internet connection. But the Bar Chart recommendation is still useful.)

Answer (score 3):

Use [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/apis/chart/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html) to create a stacked bar chart like this:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?
    cht=bhs&chs=400x150&chco=eeffee,009933&chbh=r,0.5,2.0&chds=0,120&
    chxt=x,y&chxr=0,0,120,20|1,1,5&chd=t:1,40,80,90|39,40,20,20
                                                          ^^
```

Make the first series white so it doesn't show. (I used light-green to show how it works; change `eeffee` to `ffffff` in the URL above to make it white.)

Note that you will need to calculate the widths of your actual data, e.g. for the entry [80,100] you will need to use 20 as the width, as highlighted in the URL above.

[image: Bar chart for example data]

Answer (score 2):

I can think of the type of the chart, as below. Maybe its a timeline. (Or Gantt Chart)

```
|  #######
|         ########
|                 ########
|                       #########
------------------------------------
   1     40      80    90  100  110
```

(Sorry I am kinda dazed). Probably somebody else will come up with the chart api. :D

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more polish that you want, the following will do basicaly what you need:

- [Simile TimePlot](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/) main page
- [Life of Monet](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/examples/monet/monet.html) example with different start/end times (life of monet)

In your example, I'd just use each number pair as the start,end time of each item.
It's ok if they are just numbers... see the monet example... it uses some event start/end times as simple numbers (ie: 1845 and 1846).

Using this to track lifespan of 'events' or check tickets can be very useful for seeing what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a column chart that supports start value here like [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/column/floating-chart/) or you can use a candlestick chart with open/high set to the same first value and close/low to the second.

Answer (score 0):

If you will be working with .net you can try [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/) controls. If you are in WPF or Silverlight and want something free you can try [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) or [Visifire](http://visifire.com/).

Answer (score -1):

http://pchart.sourceforge.net/
PChart for PHP is a really nice Charting Library they have an informative tutorial as well